# Is there any way to pause an activity on UI thread and test a functionality for that same activity?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am new to Espresso framework, my application has functionality where if user clicks on an app, video streaming of camera starts, but sometimes video streaming does not work and that activity remains on the screen as the thread (UI Thread) created constantly waits for the video streaming and does not become idle. I need to test a functionality where I should click on a button on that video streaming page. Is this test feasible, if yes any suggestions please? Thank you.

I tried putting delays and sleep but it did not work. Also I was thinking about runOnUiThread, but I guess problem is the activity does not stop and it won't let another activities to execute.

Expected result: user should be able to click on button on video streaming page.
Actual result: Nothing happens once video streaming page is loaded. No test are executed. Results in ResourceIdleException.

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide code and/or reproducable example?

Comment: Its ok. I raised an issue and ask developer to fix it. Thanks for the reply.